# CSS getting distorted when showHeader="true" in Vf page

Tags: visualforce, css

I have a well know issue here i have to use show `showHeader="true"` but my page's entire CSS is getting distorted. I have gone through [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000Xc97QAC) post which suggests to install VisualStrap but again only installing would suffice? or is there any other workaround.

Please let me know what can be done here.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Opportunity"
           extensions="TWL_CreditManagerCtrl" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false"
           docType="html-5.0">
```

Thorws an error:

> Attribute 'showHeader' on component <apex:page> must be false
>   when 'applyHtmlTag' is false.: Markup

Comment: What's your objective? To have a full Visualforce page with bootstrap, or just a page with bootstrap and no Visualforce/Salesforce styling?

Comment: Visualforce page with Styling applied and showHeader as True i want to show the standard Header here with Styling.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal did you get the solution?
If yes then please share.